# Excel VBA: find unique values, copy text, and copy sum to a new sheet

Tags: vba, excel, sum

I need a VBA function that will perform the following:

Find all unique values on Sheet 1, column "A", copy text from column B and column C, sum column D through G (all sums must be within the unique value).

Example:

```
#   A       B     C  D   E     F   G
--  ------- ----  -  -   ----  -  ---
1.  1110021 Job1  A  0   3000  0  200
2.  1110021 Job1  A  5   3000  0  200
3.  1110021 Job1  A  0   6000  0  200
4.  1110021 Job1  A  0   3000  2  200
5.  2254152 Job2  B  4   3000  1  400
6.  2254152 Job2  B  5   1000  1  400
7.  2254152 Job2  B  1   1000  0  400
8.  2254152 Job2  B  0   1000  0  400
9.  2254152 Job2  B  0   3000  1  400
10. 3054153 Job3  C  7   1000  4  300
11. 3054153 Job3  C  2   3000  4  600
12. 3054153 Job3  C  0   1000  4  400
```

The result would look something like this (on Sheet 2):

```
1.  1110021 Job1  A  5  15000  2    800
2.  2254152 Job2  B  10  9000  3   2000
3.  3054153 Job3  C  9   5000  12  1300
```

Can anyone help with this?

Comment: Each space between examples would be the next column...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A pivot table, as @assylias suggested would make this incredibly easy. Goto the `Data` menu option, and select `PivotTable and PivotChart Report...` (In Excel 2003)

Also, using the `Subtotals...` functionality (also under the `Data` menu in 2003) should work here as well, if you data is simple enough.

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation due to different calcs i need to do as well as exporting the information from excel to CSV, simply a pivot table alone will not work but a simple raw value copy past macro to another worksheet works perfect. Thank you Very Very Much...